# Identify last observation of a factor within a sorted data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to add a variable to my data frame that indicates which observation of a factor is the last. Essentially, what I'd like to create is indicated as the lastobs variable below.

```
id       date  val obsnum lastobs
 A 1999-01-05    5      1       0
 A 1999-01-05    9      2       0
 A 1999-02-14    4      3       1
 B 1999-03-19    7      1       1
 C 1999-02-14   10      1       1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried any particular code yet. I'm very new to R: I really just started reading about and using it earlier this week. I've looked through my reference book, "R in Action," and searched for answers to similar questions on stackoverflow. I can think of exactly how I would do it in Excel, but I'm just not familiar enough with R functions to know how to best approach this. Apologies if I've overlooked something obvious. I'm doing my best to learn quickly in a very short period of time.

Comment: If the solution helps you can accept it by checking next to the answer

Comment: Thank you. The data.table solution worked, but I'm struggling a little bit with the first solution you proposed, which uses the dplyr package. I just posted a response to the chain below. It isn't critical, but I'd like to understand why the error I described is happening (maybe this belongs in a separate post? Apologize if I'm breaking any rules here), especially if the dplyr package is, as you suggest, a good one to become familiar with for these types of exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(lastobs = +(row_number() == n()))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
# Groups: id
# 
#   id       date val obsnum lastobs
# 1  A 1999-01-05   5      1       0
# 2  A 1999-01-05   9      2       0
# 3  A 1999-02-14   4      3       1
# 4  B 1999-03-19   7      1       1
# 5  C 1999-02-14  10      1       1
```

**Explanation**

`dplyr` is a very useful package to get familiar with as a new user. It will simplify and speed up tasks like this for you. The symbol `%>%` is called a pipe and creates almost a sentence format where each statement is linked together. I first input the name of the data frame that we are using `df`, then the variable that we will group the results by `id`. We then create a new column called `lastobs` that consists of a matching command that checks if each observation is the last observation. The plus sign on the outside turns the TRUE and FALSE results into 1's and 0's.

With `base R`:

```
df$lastobs <- unlist(with(df, tapply(val, id, FUN=
                                     function(x) (seq_along(x) == length(x))+0L)))
```

With the `data.table` package (credit: @akrun):

```
setDT(df)[, lastobs := +(1:.N==.N), id]
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text='
id       date  val obsnum lastobs
 A 1999-01-05    5      1       0
 A 1999-01-05    9      2       0
 A 1999-02-14    4      3       1
 B 1999-03-19    7      1       1
 C 1999-02-14   10      1       1', header=T)

df <- df[,-5]
```

Comment: `ave` is another option, more standard when adding a vector to a df than `tapply` is: `with(df, ave(val,id,FUN=function(x) +(seq_along(x)==length(x))) )` (I'm not crazy about the base R options, in any case.) Also, you could add the data.table thing before someone else does.

Comment: I'm not crazy about the base R  approach either. It's very clunky. I just kinda missed using `tapply` And if this is a new user, I think data.table would be very confusing when subsetting in base R is a steep enough learning curve in itself.

Comment: Or using `data.table`  `setDT(df)[, lastobs := +(1:.N==.N), id]`

Comment: Thank you again for your responses. I was able to create the "lastobs" variable successfully using data.table's setDF function. However, I'm having difficulty applying the dplyr solution. Right now I'm getting an error message that reads: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : argument "x" is missing, with no default. I tried a quick Google search on that particular error message, but haven't found anything helpful yet. Could it be caused by having dplyr and data.table at the same time?

Comment: Without seeing your exact data, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Understood. I re-created a sample data frame and applied your method, which worked. There may be something else going on with my data, but I think I can play with it and figure it out from here. Thank you so much for your input and for introducing me to the dplyr package!